# Send URL in email body using play 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, mailer

How can I send an account verification link in email body using play 2.0.4 framework with Mailer API. Here is the code

```
MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();        
mail.setSubject("Complete Your Registration");
mail.addFrom(" Live Events<umair.tum@gmail.com>");
mail.addRecipient(formUser.email);
String mailBody = "Please Click on the Below Link to Complete Your Registration
"localhost:9000/verifyUser?email="+ formUser.email + "&verifyCode=" + formUser.verifierCode;
mail.send(mailBody);
```

I checked the documentation I found something like this but its for play 1.2.3

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.zenexity.fr/wp-content/themes/images/logo.png");
 String cid = email.embed(url, "Zenexity logo");
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send your message as HTML and surround your url with `<a>` tag.

```
String mailBody = "Please Click on the Below Link to Complete Your Registration
"<a href=\"http://localhost:9000/verifyUser?email="+ formUser.email + "&verifyCode=" + formUser.verifierCode + "\">click here</a>";
...
mailer.sendHtml(mailBody);
```

Comment: What's more I suggest to use common templates for building the HTML mails, all you need to use it is use ie.: `String htmlBody = views.html.mail.render(params).toString()`